# How to implement pagination or infinite scroll in FirebaseRecyclerAdapater

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using RecyclerView to show search result. Everything works perfectly fine. The RecyclerView is implemented with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Now, I want to implement pagination/infinite scroll in RecyclerView on scroll down.

1. Initial number of data on RecyclerView has to be 10 items, even though there are 100 items in the database.
2. When user swipe from bottom to top, RecyclerView has to add more data at the bottom of that 10th item.
3. RecyclerView has to load 10 more items every time it loads more data.
4. The Application must use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Please let me know if there is anything you don't understand and please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To implement infinite scroll with FirebaseUI [use the `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecyclerpagingadapter). You can configure page size there, and it will auto-load data in increments of that page size.